# Do left join and get additional from another table

Tags: database, oracle, join, left-join, inner-join

I have three tables as shown below. I need to do a left join on Customer and Order table and this is fine. After doing the left join, I need the "city" of each of the customer, and the "city" value is in ADDRESS table.

**CUSTOMER**

```
cus_id
```

**ORDERS**

```
order_id
cus_id
```

**ADDRESS**

```
cus_id
city
```

The query below returned 13 records without the inner join with ADDRESS table

```
SELECT a.cus_id, 
       b.order_id
FROM   customer a 
       LEFT JOIN orders b 
              ON a.cus_id = b.cus_id
```

This query returned 10 results with inner join on ADDRESS

```
SELECT a.cus_id, 
       b.order_id, 
       c.city 
FROM   customer a 
       LEFT JOIN orders b 
              ON a.cus_id = b.cus_id 
       INNER JOIN address c 
               ON c.cus_id = a_cus_id
```

Where did the 3 records vanish?

Comment: Could there be customers without addresses? What happens if you just inner join `customer` and `address`? How many rows do you get?

Comment: Given that a customer always has an address, the second query with inner join should have returned 13 records?

Answer (score 1):

I made a sample of the data
can you check that all customers have addresses?

```
create table customer(cus_id int);
create table orders(order_id int, cus_id int);
create table address(cus_id int, city varchar2(50));

insert into customer(cus_id) (select rownum from all_objects where rownum < 14) 
insert into orders(order_id, cus_id) select cus_id, cus_id from customer;
insert into address(cus_id, city) select cus_id, cus_id||' city' from customer;


SELECT a.cus_id, 
       b.order_id, 
       c.city 
FROM   customer a 
       LEFT JOIN orders b 
              ON a.cus_id = b.cus_id 
       INNER JOIN address c 
               ON c.cus_id = a.cus_id;
--13 records               

update address
  set city = null
where cus_id >10
```

--execute SELECT query - it returns 13 records but 3 last records have null values

```
delete from address
  where cus_id >10
```

--execute SELECT query - it returns 10 records

--check that all customers have address

```
select cus_id from customer
minus
select cus_id from address
```